# How can I get javascript to work on html that I load with json on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, json

On a particular page, I use json to load a bit of html code that displays information about what the user submitted when he clicks on something.

In this case, the user is picking his favorite baseball player and the json returns some html code that formats and displays the name of the player.

When that html is loaded on the page, the live click javascript function no longer applies to the html that is loaded. Is there some way I can refresh the javascript so that it applies to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of research and talking to several people, I found that I need to re-bind the event after the json callback.

This was a great help:
http://jetlogs.org/2009/01/29/re-binding-jquery-events-on-ajax-callbacks/

When using jQuery's .click() method and rendering new html, the javascript that was originally attached to it, needed to be attached again.

This is more easily solved by using the .live() method with the 'click' option. The .live() method automatically re-binds the new code.

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks on his favorite baseball player, you make a request to the server and it returns a json object with the players information, right? If the server returns a string containing html tags instead of a json object I don't think you are doing it the right way.

The JSON object that the server should respond with should look like the following.

```
{Name : 'Kobe Bryant', JerseyNumber : 0, Salary : 500}
```

Once you receive this object, you will parse it and put its content in an element on the page.  Responding with an HTML code is not good practice, you should create a template where your athletes data will be store.

If you give us some code along with this question, I would be more than happy to help you solve it.

Comment: It returns a json object where one variable is a string of html. So it would look something like msg.html == "<h1 class="class">Name</class>"

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but we needed to create the html on the server side to increase performance. That way, the javascript doesn't have to parse the data and create the html on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery? They have a built-in method to handle this.

```
$('#myElement').live('click', function() {
    /* Your Code Goes Here */
});
```

In jQuery 1.7 the same thing can be written as:

```
$('#myElement').on('click', function() {
    /* Your Code Goes Here */
});
```

Comment: Yes, I am using jQuery and I have that function. When the json request returns with the html that I display, the click no longer works on the html returned. The html element that I return has the same class as the original html element that I clicked on.